# Sometimes spark structured streaming job gets stuck and job remain active forever without getting killed

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, hbase, spark-structured-streaming

I am running a structured streaming application(spark version - 2.3.2). In this application I am reading data from Kafka and writing into Hbase. I have used foreach sink while writing data to Hbase.

Sometimes if anything happens at the Hbase side, like region server goes down or Hbase master goes down then streaming query that perform this operation gets stuck and remain active forever and job doesn't get killed.

I am getting below error in my spark job:

```
ApplicationRuntimeException [message=Failed 493 actions: ConnectionClosingException: 493 times, , throwable=ApplicationRuntimeException [message=Failed 493 actions: ConnectionClosingException: 493 times, , throwable=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 493 actions: ConnectionClosingException: 493 times, ]] 
    at com.sample.HBASEAPI.persist(HBASEAPI.java:423)
    at com.sample.HbaseForeachSink.writeData(HbaseForeachSink.java:185) 
    at com.sample.HbaseForeachSink.process(HbaseForeachSink.java:133)
    at com.sample.HbaseForeachSink.process(HbaseForeachSink.java:27) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink$$anonfun$addBatch$1.apply(ForeachSink.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink$$anonfun$addBatch$1.apply(ForeachSink.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: ApplicationRuntimeException [message=Failed 493 actions: ConnectionClosingException: 493 times, , throwable=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 493 actions: ConnectionClosingException: 493 times, ] 
    at com.sample.HBASEAPI.bulkFlush(HBASEAPI.java:693) at com.sample.HBASEAPI.persist(HBASEAPI.java:421) ... 15 more 
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 493 actions: ConnectionClosingException: 493 times, 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.makeException(AsyncProcess.java:235) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.access$1700(AsyncProcess.java:215) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForAllPreviousOpsAndReset(AsyncProcess.java:1753) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.backgroundFlushCommits(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:209) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.flush(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:183) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:1434) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.put(HTable.java:1030)
    at com.sample.HBASEAPI.bulkFlush(HBASEAPI.java:624)
```

What could be the reason behind this behavior? Is there any known issue regarding this?

-Hokam

Comment: Mind including any logs?

Comment: Thanks. I have added logs in question.